# JQuery Ajax send data from Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Form Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to send data from Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Form in php file. Every step has 1-4 fields. So I want the same data that send via email send also to php file.
Data that send to email are these:

```
Internet: [radio-internet]
Mobile: [radio-mobile]
Provider: [radio-provider]
Surname: [your-surname]
Name: [your-name]
Email: [your-email]
Phone: [your-phone]
Hours: [radio-hours]
```

I've tried something like this but not works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    //Form
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;

    for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    if ( 'radio-internet' == inputs[i].name &&  'radio-mobile' == inputs[i].name &&  && 'radio-provider' == inputs[i].name && 'your-surname' == inputs[i].name &&  'your-name' == inputs[i].name  &&  'your-email' == inputs[i].name  &&  'your-phone' == inputs[i].name  &&  'radio-hours' == inputs[i].name ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url  : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST 
            type : 'post',
            data :  inputs,
            success : function( response ){
                console.log(response);
                console.log('lead inserted');
            },
            error : function(e1, e2, e3){
                console.log(e1);
                console.log(e2);
                console.log(e3);
            }
        });
        console.log( event.detail );
    }

}, false );
</script>
```

Attention: every field must go to different field in php file

```
$data = array(
"lastname" => "" . $_POST['surname'], //surname
"firstname" => "" . $_POST['name'], //name
"mobile" => "" . $_POST['phone'], //mobile
"email" => "" . $_POST['email'], //email
);
```

Comment: what do you want to do with these datas? because contact form 7 has some filters using that you can do many thing. so tell me what is the use why you want in php file?

Comment: I want these data send also in vtiger crm automatic on last submit button.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the contact form 7 before email send hook.

Right now I just stored the data in one text file you can add your logic here.

```
 add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'd_before_send_email' );

 function d_before_send_email($cf7) {
    $output = "";
    $output .= "Name: " . $_POST['name'];
    $output .= "Email: " . $_POST['email'];       

    file_put_contents("contactform7output.txt", $output);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'wpcf7mailsent' event , Its works for me.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    
            var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    
            
                var username = document.getElementById('username').value; // OR jQuery( "#username" ).val();

                var email = document.getElementById('email').value; // OR jQuery( "#email" ).val();
                
    
                jQuery.ajax({
                   url  : <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>, // the url where we want to POST 
                type : 'post',
                data :  {action:second_form,username:username,email:email},
                success : function( response ){
                    console.log(response);
                    
                },
                  error: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  },
                });
                alert('hi');
            
    
        }, false );
```

## Ajax action function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_second_form' , 'second_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_second_form','second_form');
function second_form(){
echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_POST['email'];
//do for second form
}
```

Comment: The contact form id 123 is the last one form? How read the data from all forms because I use Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Form.

Comment: remove if condition , it is only the example

Comment: I received an error : (index):383 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null. 

383 var internet = document.getElementById('radio-internet').value; So can't read the data from other forms?

Comment: It doesn't work for me... How to save data from other forms and after send all data to url where we want to post the data? With your solution in every step I see that send data in every form, when I click the submit button to every form